# reporting services and custom datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm new to reporting services and ask for the possibily of using custom object as datasource? i'm using asp.net, visual web developer 2008 express edition and c#, if yes can you give an example. thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use POCO as a data source directly in reporting services. There are a few ways to do this.

The simplest it to save your data to a database and query the database.

You could serialize the object to XML and query that by either including the XML directly into your query in an `<XmlData>` element, or calling a web service to retrieve the XML.

Create an XML Data Source for a Web Service

1. In your report project, right click on the Shared Data Sources folder.
2. Select Add New Data Source.
3. Set the Name to use.
4. Set the Type to XML.
5. Set the connection string to http://MyWebServer/MyWebServiceEndpoint.asmx.
6. Go to the Credentials page.
7. Configure the authentication.
8. Click OK.

You'll need to examine the WSDL for the web service and see the following references to help you build the query:

1. [Reporting Services: Using XML and Web Service Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa964129.aspx)
2. [XML Query Syntax for XML Report Data (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345251.aspx)
3. [Element Path Syntax for XML Report Data (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365158.aspx)

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try simply to use Datasets even i don't like theme

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of supported data sources from msdn: [Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219.aspx)

You would simply add a shared data source to your project (example: MyDataSource.rds) and choose from the available types.  There, you would simply supply the appropriate credentials.  Each of your reports would use the data source.

**EDIT**

Here's a simple tutorial on adding a data source: [Creating a Shared Data Source in Reporting Services](http://blog.infotoad.com/post/2009/07/02/Creating-a-Shared-Data-Source-in-Reporting-Services-2008.aspx)

Comment: I can't find any item with the *.rds extention within vwd express 2008, and the list you provided doesn't montion POCO as datasource

Comment: Either Microsoft forgot to list it, or Microsoft doesn't support it.  That list is right from the horses mouth.  Updated answer to include a how-to on creating a shared data source.  Cheers!